# Leaflet map layers not working on my PyQt5 interface and Chrome/Chromium Browser

Tags: javascript, html, pyqt, leaflet, maps

I'm working on a PyQt5 project that uses gdal to divide a geotif and show it using generate a html + Leaftlet library to show the results.

I'm having problem to show the results on Chrome/Chromium Browser and PyQt5 (I read that it uses Chromium on background). I tested on Firefox (Linux and Windows) and Microsoft Edge (Windows) and it worked fine.

This is an html sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
          <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no' />
            <title>FazMaraneyRGB_transparent_mosaic_group1</title>

            <!-- Leaflet -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href=/home/gabrielschubert/Documents/hawkit_app/guis/pyqt_gui/leaflet/leaflet.css />
            <script src=/home/gabrielschubert/Documents/hawkit_app/guis/pyqt_gui/leaflet/leaflet.js ></script>

            <!-- Leaflet.draw -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href=/home/gabrielschubert/Documents/hawkit_app/guis/pyqt_gui/leaflet/draw/leaflet.draw.css />
            <script src=/home/gabrielschubert/Documents/hawkit_app/guis/pyqt_gui/leaflet/draw/leaflet.draw.js ></script>

            <!-- Leaflet Ajax -->
            <script src=/home/gabrielschubert/Documents/hawkit_app/guis/pyqt_gui/leaflet/ajax/dist/leaflet.ajax.js ></script>

            <!-- Leaflet Measument -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href=/home/gabrielschubert/Documents/hawkit_app/guis/pyqt_gui/leaflet/measurement/leaflet-measure.css />
            <script src=/home/gabrielschubert/Documents/hawkit_app/guis/pyqt_gui/leaflet/measurement/leaflet-measure.js ></script>


            <style>
                body { margin:0; padding:0; }
                body, table, tr, td, th, div, h1, h2, input { font-family: "Calibri", "Trebuchet MS", "Ubuntu", Serif; font-size: 11pt; }
                #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; } /* full size */
                .ctl {
                    padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px;
                    background: white;
                    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
                    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
                    border-radius: 5px;
                    text-align: right;
                }
                .title {
                    font-size: 18pt;
                    font-weight: bold;
                }
                .src {
                    font-size: 10pt;
                }
                #delete, #export {
                    position: absolute;
                    top:100px;
                    right:10px;
                    z-index:100;
                    background:white;
                    color:black;
                    padding:6px;
                    border-radius:4px;
                    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
                    cursor: pointer;
                    font-size:12px;
                    text-decoration:none;
                }
                #export {
                    top:130px;
                }
            </style>

        </head>
        <body>

        <div id='map'></div>
        <div id='delete'>Delete Features</div>
        <a href='#' id='export'>Export Features</a>

        <script>
        /* **** Leaflet **** */

        // Base layers
        //  .. OpenStreetMap
        var osm = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'});

        //  .. White background
        var white = L.tileLayer("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQAAAAEAAQMAAABmvDolAAAAA1BMVEX///+nxBvIAAAAH0lEQVQYGe3BAQ0AAADCIPunfg43YAAAAAAAAAAA5wIhAAAB9aK9BAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");

        // Overlay layers (TMS)
        var lyr1 = L.tileLayer('./tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {tms: true, maxZoom: 22, opacity: 0.9, attribution: ""});

        // Map
        var map = L.map('map', {
            measureControl: true,
            center: [-18.3604868606589, -52.694255477616245],
            zoom: 22,
            minZoom: 0,
            maxZoom: 22,
            layers: [osm]
        });

        lyr1.addTo(map);


        function getColor(d) {
            return d > 0.65 ? '#196619' :
                d > 0.60  ? '#248f24' :
                d > 0.55  ? '#2eb82e' :
                d > 0.50  ? '#47d147' :
                d > 0.45   ? '#85e085' :
                d > 0.40   ? '#adebad' :
                d > 0.35   ? '#d6f5d6' :
                            '#cc8033';
        }
        function style(feature) {
            return {
                fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.area),
                weight: 2,
                opacity: 0.6,
                color: 'white',
                dashArray: '3',
                fillOpacity: 0.7
            };
        }

        //Geojson Layers


        var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("fields/data_divisions/vector0.geojson", {style: style});
        geojsonLayer.addTo(map);

        //THIS VAR ABOVE REPEATS DEPENDING THE NUMBER OS VECTOR I HAVE. I PUT ONLY ONE BECAUSE OF NUMBER OS CHARACTERS STACKOVERFLOW ALLOWED ME. ON THE IMAGE I'M SHOWING A RESULT WITH 2500 VECTORS.



        var basemaps = {"OpenStreetMap": osm, "Without background": white}
        var overlaymaps = {"Layer 1": lyr1}

        // Title
        var title = L.control();
        title.onAdd = function(map) {
            this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'ctl title');
            this.update();
            return this._div;
        };
        title.update = function(props) {
            this._div.innerHTML = "FazMaraneyRGB_transparent_mosaic_group1";
        };
        title.addTo(map);

        // Note
        var src = 'Generated by Hawkit';
        var title = L.control({position: 'bottomleft'});
        title.onAdd = function(map) {
            this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'ctl src');
            this.update();
            return this._div;
        };
        title.update = function(props) {
            this._div.innerHTML = src;
        };
        title.addTo(map);

        var featureGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

        var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
            edit: {
                featureGroup: featureGroup
            }
        }).addTo(map);

        map.on('draw:created', function(e) {

            // Each time a feaute is created, it's added to the over arching feature group
            featureGroup.addLayer(e.layer);
        });

        // on click, clear all layers
        document.getElementById('delete').onclick = function(e) {
            featureGroup.clearLayers();
        }

        document.getElementById('export').onclick = function(e) {
            // Extract GeoJson from featureGroup
            var data = featureGroup.toGeoJSON();

            // Stringify the GeoJson
            var convertedData = 'text/json;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));

            // Create export
            document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('href', 'data:' + convertedData);
            document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('download','data.geojson');
        }


        // Add base layers
        L.control.layers(basemaps, overlaymaps, {collapsed: true}).addTo(map);

        // Fit to overlay bounds (SW and NE points with (lat, lon))
        map.fitBounds([[-18.36827062251916, -52.6871074784942], [-18.35270287637126, -52.7014028427423]]);

        </script>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Same html opened on Firefox and Chromium

[image: Firefox]
[image: Chromium]

Using:

PyQt5 v5.9

Python 3.6.5

Chromium Version 65.0.3325.181

Firefox 59.0.2 (64-bit).

Leaflet 1.3.1

Leaflet Draw 1.0.2 (https://unpkg.com/leaflet-draw@1.0.2/)

Leaflet Ajax 2.1.0 (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-ajax/2.1.0/leaflet.ajax.min.js)

Leaflet Measure (http://ljagis.github.io/leaflet-measure/leaflet-measure.css)

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: You can share all the dependencies in a zip file and provide the download link.

Comment: Hello @eyllanesc. The problem is that the html I've posted is working on Firefox and Microsoft Edge, but opening with problem on Chrome/Chromium and PyQt5 interface (using QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()). The green layer just doesn't become visible. I can upload everything and send to you, but the data is ~2-3GB, so it'll take time. Regards.

Comment: Does the dependency weigh so much? can you share me the .geojson.

Comment: This is one of the .geojson I'm using:

{"type": "FeatureCollection", "name": "data", "features": [{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-52.698703122145425, -18.35937182458476], [-52.69875976967515, -18.359100206942212], [-52.69852765931118, -18.359100206942212], [-52.69852765931118, -18.35937182458476], [-52.698703122145425, -18.35937182458476]]]}, "properties": {"area": 0.6165038467027335}}]}

Comment: Here you can find all of them:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dcwycBhmzlC1nJijKiIeJX3tIa21MJn0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I do not get the map window without content, so I can not help you, if you provide me with a [mcve], with all the dependencies to download I could review where the problem is, for now I will not be able to do anything.